# Generating a Material3 theme based on a single arbitrary input color and applying it to Activities

Tags: android, android-theme, material3

I've set up my app to use Material3 colors roles and theme, and added an option to enable Material You support using DynamicColors.

However, I would also like the user to be able to select a single (preferably arbitrary) input color within the app, and have the app generate all the color roles and apply a theme from that. I feel like this should be possible somehow given that Material You is doing this based on the wallpaper colors, but don't really a way to do this for an arbitrary color. Is it possible?

Answer (score 1):

Have you taken a look at these two links?

- https://m3.material.io/styles/color/the-color-system/tokens
- https://m3.material.io/styles/color/the-color-system/custom-colors

They describe what you're talking about, I am unsure of what implementation looks like on the code side. But to answer the question "Is it possible?", it looks like it.

This link describes how the dynamic color palletes are generated:

> A dynamic tonal palette must be generated from a single source color that should be derived from wallpaper using com.android.systemui.monet.ColorScheme#getSeedColors, which provides multiple valid source colors. If none of the provided colors meet the source color requirement, the single source color should use the value 0xFF1B6EF3.

- https://source.android.com/docs/core/display/dynamic-color#how_is_a_dynamic_tonal_pallet_generated

Here is the actual file from the AOSP if you wanted to look at how the actual dynamic color code works:

```java
/*
 * Copyright (C) 2021 The Android Open Source Project
 *  * Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
 * you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
 * You may obtain a copy of the License at
 *  *      http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
 *  * Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
 * distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
 * WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
 * See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
 * limitations under the License.
 */
package com.android.systemui.monet
import android.annotation.ColorInt
import android.app.WallpaperColors
import android.graphics.Color
import com.android.internal.graphics.ColorUtils
import com.android.internal.graphics.cam.Cam
import com.android.internal.graphics.cam.CamUtils.lstarFromInt
import kotlin.math.absoluteValue
import kotlin.math.roundToInt
const val TAG = "ColorScheme"
const val ACCENT1_CHROMA = 48.0f
const val ACCENT2_CHROMA = 16.0f
const val ACCENT3_CHROMA = 32.0f
const val ACCENT3_HUE_SHIFT = 60.0f
const val NEUTRAL1_CHROMA = 4.0f
const val NEUTRAL2_CHROMA = 8.0f
const val GOOGLE_BLUE = 0xFF1b6ef3.toInt()
const val MIN_CHROMA = 5
public class ColorScheme(@ColorInt seed: Int, val darkTheme: Boolean) {
    val accent1: List<Int>
    val accent2: List<Int>
    val accent3: List<Int>
    val neutral1: List<Int>
    val neutral2: List<Int>
    constructor(wallpaperColors: WallpaperColors, darkTheme: Boolean):
            this(getSeedColor(wallpaperColors), darkTheme)
    val allAccentColors: List<Int>
        get() {
            val allColors = mutableListOf<Int>()
            allColors.addAll(accent1)
            allColors.addAll(accent2)
            allColors.addAll(accent3)
            return allColors
        }
    val allNeutralColors: List<Int>
        get() {
            val allColors = mutableListOf<Int>()
            allColors.addAll(neutral1)
            allColors.addAll(neutral2)
            return allColors
        }
    val backgroundColor
        get() = ColorUtils.setAlphaComponent(if (darkTheme) neutral1[8] else neutral1[0], 0xFF)
    val accentColor
        get() = ColorUtils.setAlphaComponent(if (darkTheme) accent1[2] else accent1[6], 0xFF)
    init {
        val proposedSeedCam = Cam.fromInt(seed)
        val seedArgb = if (seed == Color.TRANSPARENT) {
            GOOGLE_BLUE
        } else if (proposedSeedCam.chroma < 5) {
            GOOGLE_BLUE
        } else {
            seed
        }
        val camSeed = Cam.fromInt(seedArgb)
        val hue = camSeed.hue
        val chroma = camSeed.chroma.coerceAtLeast(ACCENT1_CHROMA)
        val tertiaryHue = wrapDegrees((hue + ACCENT3_HUE_SHIFT).toInt())
        accent1 = Shades.of(hue, chroma).toList()
        accent2 = Shades.of(hue, ACCENT2_CHROMA).toList()
        accent3 = Shades.of(tertiaryHue.toFloat(), ACCENT3_CHROMA).toList()
        neutral1 = Shades.of(hue, NEUTRAL1_CHROMA).toList()
        neutral2 = Shades.of(hue, NEUTRAL2_CHROMA).toList()
    }
    override fun toString(): String {
        return "ColorScheme {\n" +
                "  neutral1: ${humanReadable(neutral1)}\n" +
                "  neutral2: ${humanReadable(neutral2)}\n" +
                "  accent1: ${humanReadable(accent1)}\n" +
                "  accent2: ${humanReadable(accent2)}\n" +
                "  accent3: ${humanReadable(accent3)}\n" +
                "}"
    }
    companion object {
        /**
         * Identifies a color to create a color scheme from.
         *
         * @param wallpaperColors Colors extracted from an image via quantization.
         * @return ARGB int representing the color
         */
        @JvmStatic
        @ColorInt
        fun getSeedColor(wallpaperColors: WallpaperColors): Int {
            return getSeedColors(wallpaperColors).first()
        }
        /**
         * Filters and ranks colors from WallpaperColors.
         *
         * @param wallpaperColors Colors extracted from an image via quantization.
         * @return List of ARGB ints, ordered from highest scoring to lowest.
         */
        @JvmStatic
        fun getSeedColors(wallpaperColors: WallpaperColors): List<Int> {
            val totalPopulation = wallpaperColors.allColors.values.reduce { a, b -> a + b }
                    .toDouble()
            val totalPopulationMeaningless = (totalPopulation == 0.0)
            if (totalPopulationMeaningless) {
                // WallpaperColors with a population of 0 indicate the colors didn't come from
                // quantization. Instead of scoring, trust the ordering of the provided primary
                // secondary/tertiary colors.
                //
                // In this case, the colors are usually from a Live Wallpaper.
                val distinctColors = wallpaperColors.mainColors.map {
                    it.toArgb()
                }.distinct().filter {
                    Cam.fromInt(it).chroma >= MIN_CHROMA
                }.toList()
                if (distinctColors.isEmpty()) {
                    return listOf(GOOGLE_BLUE)
                }
                return distinctColors
            }
            val intToProportion = wallpaperColors.allColors.mapValues {
                it.value.toDouble() / totalPopulation
            }
            val intToCam = wallpaperColors.allColors.mapValues { Cam.fromInt(it.key) }
            // Get an array with 360 slots. A slot contains the percentage of colors with that hue.
            val hueProportions = huePopulations(intToCam, intToProportion)
            // Map each color to the percentage of the image with its hue.
            val intToHueProportion = wallpaperColors.allColors.mapValues {
                val cam = intToCam[it.key]!!
                val hue = cam.hue.roundToInt()
                var proportion = 0.0
                for (i in hue - 15..hue + 15) {
                    proportion += hueProportions[wrapDegrees(i)]
                }
                proportion
            }
            // Remove any inappropriate seed colors. For example, low chroma colors look grayscale
            // raising their chroma will turn them to a much louder color that may not have been
            // in the image.
            val filteredIntToCam = intToCam.filter {
                val cam = it.value
                val lstar = lstarFromInt(it.key)
                val proportion = intToHueProportion[it.key]!!
                cam.chroma >= MIN_CHROMA &&
                        (totalPopulationMeaningless || proportion > 0.01)
            }
            // Sort the colors by score, from high to low.
            val intToScoreIntermediate = filteredIntToCam.mapValues {
                score(it.value, intToHueProportion[it.key]!!)
            }
            val intToScore = intToScoreIntermediate.entries.toMutableList()
            intToScore.sortByDescending { it.value }
            // Go through the colors, from high score to low score.
            // If the color is distinct in hue from colors picked so far, pick the color.
            // Iteratively decrease the amount of hue distinctness required, thus ensuring we
            // maximize difference between colors.
            val minimumHueDistance = 15
            val seeds = mutableListOf<Int>()
            maximizeHueDistance@ for (i in 90 downTo minimumHueDistance step 1) {
                seeds.clear()
                for (entry in intToScore) {
                    val int = entry.key
                    val existingSeedNearby = seeds.find {
                        val hueA = intToCam[int]!!.hue
                        val hueB = intToCam[it]!!.hue
                        hueDiff(hueA, hueB) < i } != null
                    if (existingSeedNearby) {
                        continue
                    }
                    seeds.add(int)
                    if (seeds.size >= 4) {
                        break@maximizeHueDistance
                    }
                }
            }
            if (seeds.isEmpty()) {
                // Use gBlue 500 if there are 0 colors
                seeds.add(GOOGLE_BLUE)
            }
            return seeds
        }
        private fun wrapDegrees(degrees: Int): Int {
            return when {
                degrees < 0 -> {
                    (degrees % 360) + 360
                }
                degrees >= 360 -> {
                    degrees % 360
                }
                else -> {
                    degrees
                }
            }
        }
        private fun hueDiff(a: Float, b: Float): Float {
            return 180f - ((a - b).absoluteValue - 180f).absoluteValue
        }
        private fun humanReadable(colors: List<Int>): String {
            return colors.joinToString { "#" + Integer.toHexString(it) }
        }
        private fun score(cam: Cam, proportion: Double): Double {
            val proportionScore = 0.7 * 100.0 * proportion
            val chromaScore = if (cam.chroma < ACCENT1_CHROMA) 0.1 * (cam.chroma - ACCENT1_CHROMA)
            else 0.3 * (cam.chroma - ACCENT1_CHROMA)
            return chromaScore + proportionScore
        }
        private fun huePopulations(
            camByColor: Map<Int, Cam>,
            populationByColor: Map<Int, Double>
        ): List<Double> {
            val huePopulation = List(size = 360, init = { 0.0 }).toMutableList()
            for (entry in populationByColor.entries) {
                val population = populationByColor[entry.key]!!
                val cam = camByColor[entry.key]!!
                val hue = cam.hue.roundToInt() % 360
                if (cam.chroma <= MIN_CHROMA) {
                    continue
                }
                huePopulation[hue] = huePopulation[hue] + population
            }
            return huePopulation
        }
    }
}
```

- https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/refs/tags/android-12.1.0_r1/packages/SystemUI/monet/src/com/android/systemui/monet/ColorScheme.kt

Going off of this, mind you I haven't tested this, the code would probably look like this:

```java
// Get user color input somehow
val userColor = getUserColor();

// Reference:
// public class ColorScheme(@ColorInt seed: Int, val darkTheme: Boolean)

// Color input needs to be an integer, assuming the color code would probably start in hex
// Using false for darkMode for example purposes
val colorScheme = ColorScheme(userColor.toInt(), false)
val accent1Colors = colorScheme.accent1
val accent2Colors = colorScheme.accent2
val accent3Colors = colorScheme.accent3
val neutral1Colors = colorScheme.neutral1
val neutral2Colors = colorScheme.neutral2
```

Hopefully you found this helpful

Comment: Hmm, it looks like Google doesn't want app developers doing this, even if I managed to cobble together a working ColorScheme class from the AOSP, I don't see a way of applying the generated colors to the app.

Comment: @SteveM in compose you can dynamically change the theme colors without issues, this does not work with the xml theme though.